# Why app crashing? NullPointerException when assigning Arraylist to Array

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

```
Exhibit[] listOfEx = exhibits.toArray(new Exhibit[exhibits.size()]);;
        String[] listOfSt = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < exhibits.size(); i++){
            Log.d("DEBUG", String.valueOf(exhibits.size()));
            listOfSt[i] = listOfEx[i].getName();
            Log.d("DEBUG", listOfSt[i]);
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                        R.layout.listview_item, listOfSt));
```

My app crashes where it assigns in loop. I get this:

07-18 22:43:32.760: E/AndroidRuntime(28545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.foothill.junk/edu.foothill.junk.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Please let me know if more info needed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Point out which line the exception occured on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect this code to do?

String[] listOfSt = null;

It creates a null variable, right?

And then you use the null variable (without having initialized it first):

```
 listOfSt[i] = listOfEx[i].getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the array `listOfSt` with an empty array, not `null`:

```
String[] listOfSt = new String[length];
```

where `length` will be the length of the array, so it will depend on how many items you want it to store. If you want it to have the same length than `listOfEx`, you can use

```
String[] listOfSt = new String[listOfEx.length];
```